# Null Pointer Exception when accessing the serial port

Tags: java, serial-port, nullpointerexception

I have a Java project (in NetBeans 7.1) and I am receiving the following `NullPointerException`:

```
run:
Port COM10 not found.
The serial port you are trying to use is currently in usejava.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mateorssms.Communicator.ListenOnPort(Communicator.java:68)
    at mateorssms.Communicator.<init>(Communicator.java:35)
    at mateorssms.MateorsSMS.main(MateorsSMS.java:14)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second).
```

So my MateorsSMS class is:

```
package mateorssms;

import java.awt.Frame;


public class MateorsSMS{    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //UserInterface UI = new UserInterface();
    //UI.setVisible(true);
    new Communicator();        
    // TODO code application logic here
}
}
```

and Communicator class (different class in a different file) is

```
package mateorssms;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.comm.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;


public class Communicator implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener{

static Enumeration portList;
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
boolean portFound = false;    
SerialPort serialPort;
String defaultPort = "COM10"; 
Thread readThread;
InputStream inputStream;



public Communicator(){
    getPort();  
    ListenOnPort();
}




private void getPort(){  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    portFound = false;
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while(portList.hasMoreElements() && !(portFound)){
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if(portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL){
            if(portId.getName().equals(defaultPort)){
                System.out.println("Found port: " + defaultPort);
                portFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!portFound){
        System.err.println("Port " + defaultPort + " not found."); //user feedback
        //System.exit(1);            
    }
}

private void ListenOnPort(){
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MateorsSMSApp", 300);
        System.out.println("yes");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The serial port you are trying to use is currently in use"+e.toString());
    }

    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(inputStream.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Ex");
    }
    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
        System.err.println("Ex");
    }
    // activate the DATA_AVAILABLE notifier
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {           
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(460800,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        serialPort.setDTR(true);
        serialPort.setRTS(true);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
        System.err.println("Ex");
    }

    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();
}



@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI: System.out.println("BI"); // Break interruptbreak;
        case SerialPortEvent.OE: System.out.println("OE");// Overrun error break;
        case SerialPortEvent.FE: System.out.println("FE");// Framing error break;
        case SerialPortEvent.PE: System.out.println("PE");// Parity error break;
        case SerialPortEvent.CD: System.out.println("CD");//Carrier detected break;
        case SerialPortEvent.CTS: System.out.println("CTS");//Clear to send break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DSR: System.out.println("DSR");// Data set ready break;
        case SerialPortEvent.RI: System.out.println("RI");// Ring indicator break;
        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY: System.out.println("OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY"); //break;
        //break; //Buffer empty

        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE: //Data Available to be read

            System.out.println("DATA_AVAILABLE");
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20]; 

            try {

                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                }

                String result = new String(readBuffer);
                System.out.println(result);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Ex");
            }
            break;
    }
    //SerialPort port;
    // TODO do something with ev
}


@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex){
        System.err.println("Ex");

    }

}            
}
```

Comment: Looks like the COM port you're trying to use is busy. Try different serial ports until you come to know it's not in use.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this line:

```
serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MateorsSMSApp", 300);
```

throws an exception, which probably means that `serialPort` is still null after that line because the call to `open` failed.

Then on the next try block you have the following line, which would throw a NPE if `serialPort` is null:

```
inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
```

It would make your life easier if you only had one try/catch block in the `ListenOnPort` method instead of 3.

Note: method names in Java generally start with a lower case: `ListenOnPort` => `listenOnPort`

Answer (score 0):

You get three exception messages:

```
Port COM10 not found.
```

This message is produced in `getPort()`. Probably `portId` is still null after returning from that method.

```
The serial port you are trying to use is currently in usejava.lang.NullPointerException
```

This message is produced in the first try-block of `ListenOnPort()`. See the end "java.lang.NullPointerException" of that message. This supports the claim that `portId` ist null.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Now as noted by assylias, the call `serialPort.getInputStream()` fails, because `serialPort` is null, too.

I suggest you improve the error reporting, e.g. print messages and stack traces of exceptions you catch with `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.err.println("Ex")`.

Comment: agree with the error reporting, though logging it into a file or DB is better than printing the exception stacktrace on the `err` or `out` console.

Comment: Of course it is. Using a proper logging framework, one can configure the log message destination(s) without altering the program.